# Find the curl of $\mathrm a \times ( \mathrm b \times \mathrm r)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, cross-product

I'm trying to find the curl of $a \times (b \times r)$ where $a$, $b$ are constant vectors and $r = (x,y,z)$.

I've worked through the problem to achieve the following answer:

$$(\vec a \cdot \vec r) (\nabla \times \vec b) + \nabla (\vec a \cdot \vec r) \times \vec b - (\vec a \cdot \vec b) (\nabla \times \vec r) - \nabla (\vec a \cdot \vec b) \times \vec r$$

I know that the final answer is, $a \times b$, however I'm unsure of the steps in between to get there. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off the top of my head, two of those terms are clearly zero because you're taking the (or rather *a*) derivative of a constant vector field.  Edit: then there's another zero term because it involves a measure of the rotation of the radial vector field (which clearly doesn't produce any rotations at all).  The term that's left over is easy enough simplify.

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks for the help, I kind of understand where your going. Could you please expand on your comment?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @Bye_World I'm unsure of how three of the terms become zero. Could you please explain to me the nature of constant and radial vector fields in this problem? Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Example: $\vec b$ is a constant vector field.  $\nabla \times$ is a type of derivative (called the curl).  So without calculating anything you should be able to see that $\nabla \times \vec b=0$ because you're taking the derivative of a constant.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{r}) &=
  (\mathbf{a \cdot r}) \mathbf{b}-(\mathbf{a \cdot b}) \mathbf{r} \\[5pt]
  \nabla \times [\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{r})] &=
  \nabla \times [(\mathbf{a \cdot r}) \mathbf{b}]-
  (\mathbf{a \cdot b}) \nabla \times \mathbf{r} \\[5pt]
  &=
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{e}_{x} & \mathbf{e}_{y} & \mathbf{e}_{z} \\
    \partial_{x} & \partial_{y} & \partial_{z} \\
    (\mathbf{a \cdot r}) b_x &
    (\mathbf{a \cdot r}) b_y &
    (\mathbf{a \cdot r}) b_z \\
  \end{vmatrix} - \mathbf{0} \\[5pt]
  &= \sum_{xyz} \mathbf{e}_{x}
     \left \{ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [(\mathbf{a\cdot r}) b_{z}]-
     \frac{\partial}{\partial z} [(\mathbf{a\cdot r}) b_{y}] \right \} \\[5pt]
  &= \sum_{xyz} \, \mathbf{e}_{x} (a_{y} b_{z}-a_{z} b_{y}) \\[5pt]
  &= \mathbf{a\times b}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for answering. However some of the notation that you've used, I'm sadly unfamiliar with. Would it thus be possible, if you could please add in an explanation to improve your answer, thanks.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this kind of problems usually I use levi-civita symbol.

$(a\times b)_{k}=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_{i}b_{j}$

In this case:

First, you have to notice any differential operation over a constant vector is zero. Therefore, $(\nabla\times[\vec{a}\times(\vec{b}\times\vec{r})])_{s}=\varepsilon_{pqs}\partial_{p}[\vec{a}\times(\vec{b}\times\vec{r})]_{q}=\varepsilon_{pqs}\partial_{p}(\varepsilon_{ijq}a_{i}(\vec{b}\times\vec{r})_{j})=\varepsilon_{pqs}\partial_{p}(\varepsilon_{ijq}a_{i}\varepsilon_{nmj}b_{n}x_{m})=\varepsilon_{pqs}\partial_{p}(\varepsilon_{jqi}\varepsilon_{jnm}a_{i}b_{n}x_{m})=\varepsilon_{pqs}\partial_{p}([\delta_{qn}\delta_{im}-\delta_{qm}\delta_{in}]a_{i}b_{n}x_{m})=\varepsilon_{pqs}([\delta_{qn}\delta_{im}-\delta_{qm}\delta_{in}]a_{i}b_{n}\delta_{mp})=\varepsilon_{pqs}([\delta_{qn}\delta_{ip}-\delta_{qp}\delta_{in}]a_{i}b_{n})=\varepsilon_{pqs}(a_{p}b_{q}-0)=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$